# "dotnet run" command execution failed

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-mvc, ubuntu-20.04

I installed .net in my ubuntu20.04 to build asp .net core mvc web project.

Here is info:
`$dotnet --info`

```
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.203
 Commit:    5b005c19f5

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  20.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.20.04-x64
 Base Path:   /snap/dotnet-sdk/199/sdk/7.0.203/

Host:
  Version:      7.0.5
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       8042d61b17

.NET SDKs installed:
  7.0.203 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/199/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.5 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/199/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.5 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/199/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

first I run command `dotnet new mvc` in vs code terminal mvc project is created.

Then when I run `dotnet run` command, this happens

> Building...
> command execution failed

Comment: Is `Command Execution Failed` the only error message you are getting after running `dotnet run`? Normally something follows after.

Comment: @Bram Yes, after this error message, new $ line is started automatically.

Comment: Try this to add more to the output: `dotnet run --verbosity diag` (see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This dotnet was installed via Snap. Unfortunately, snap is quite broken at the moment. Users have run into various errors including segfaults.

Even the official [snap installation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-snap) says:

> Snap installations of .NET may have problems ...

IMO, that's very generous phrasing - snap versions of .NET are completely/randomly broken. On Ubuntu 20.04, you can try [installing via the Microsoft package feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu-2004). Or [using a tarball or the dotnet-install script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual).